# "as it so happens" idiom meaning and usage

Tags: idioms

What is the meaning of "As it so happens" and when do we use it? Refer to a synonym if you can please. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_it_happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"As it so happens" is used as a connector phrase to bridge parts of a conversation, usually things that are closely related or lead into each other.  Might be in reference to an unexpected or unlikely fact.[1](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it+just+so+happens)

Example:

"My car just broke down."

"As it so happens, my husband is a mechanic."

Phrases that could be used similarly:

- You're [just] in luck...
- Well, actually...
- Now that you mention it...
- You know what?

Keep in mind, the above aren't synonyms, but they can frequently be used interchangeably.

Comment: You're quite welcome.